# Generic theme not overriding default styles

Tags: wpf, xaml

For some reason, I can't find why my `generic.xaml` does not override default style.

Everything is contains in a `Themes` folder and `Styles` are still available via intellisense but I must set them manually on each controls, for example here on a `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox
    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxBase}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemBase}"
    />
```

My Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ComboBox.xaml"/>
        <!--other resources goes here-->
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

My App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Part of the ResourceDictionary for the ComboBox :

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxBase" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
    <!--other setters goes here-->
```

I wish I could have my `Themes` to be default everywhere.

thx

Comment: Note that `Themes/Generic.xaml` is supposed to contain the default Styles of custom controls in a control library. There is no need to reuse that name for what you are doing here.

Comment: which name are we talking about ?

Comment: Themes/Generic.xaml. Besides that, setting `x:Key` on a Style resource prevents that it's used as default Style.

Comment: I don't need to reuse the name "Themes/Generic.xaml" in App.xaml ?

Comment: As already said, you only need to use the special name `Themes/Generic.xaml` for a ResourceDictioary that is supposed to contain the default Styles of custom controls in a control library. You can call yours how ever you like.

Comment: the `x:key` solved the problem. My Themes/Generic.xaml, actually contains all my  default style for my app, the combobox is retemplated for example.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted you tell you, that it is **not mandatory** to use that file name for your ResourceDictionary. That special file name is meant to serve a different purpose, hence your naming is a little confusing.

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought it has to be named that way. But if merged in app.xaml, as I understand then the name doesn't matter.